# How to use an object key in another object's path?

Tags: javascript

I have the following objects:

```
var obj1 {
key1: "path"
};

var obj2 {
path: "done"
};
```

I want to get "done" (obj2.path) in the scope of obj1 key1.
So the key "path" shall not be reached by obj2.path, but by obj1.key1.

Something like: obj2.(obj1.key1)?

i hope you can understand, sorry for my english :)

Comment: `obj2[obj1.key1]` as per the linked duplicate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `[]` notation to access property, which derived from `obj1` key.

```js
var obj1= {
key1: "path"
};

var obj2= {
path: "done"
};

console.log(obj2[obj1.key1]);
```